# Python Tkinter OOP Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to inherit some values from one class to a another one. I am using the function super to inherit. Below is a simplfied version of my problem. Thank you for help.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
class First(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(First, self).__init__(master)
    def random(self):
        self._y = random.randint(11,20)
        self._x = random.randint(1,10)
    def random2(self):
        s = First(root)
        s.random()


class Second(Frame,First):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Second, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.menuFrame = Frame(self)
        self.create_menu_widgets()
        self.menuFrame.grid()
    def create_menu_widgets(self):
          btnMainMenu = Button(self.menuFrame,font=("consolas",18,"bold"),text="Main Menu")
          btnMainMenu.pack()
    def print(self):
        print(self._y,self._x)



root = Tk()
x = Second(root)
x.random()
x.random2()
x.print()
root.configure(background   = 'green')
root.mainloop()
```

I keep on getting the error:

```
super(First, self).__init__(master)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Please help me, I think the problem is where I have s=First(root). Thanks for help.

Comment: Why `class First(object)` ? Don't you mean `Frame` instead of object?

Comment: You don't need to call super if it is object.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new instance of the class from inside the class? `s = First(root)`?

Comment: Deriving from `object` was required to be explicit, but not anymore in Python3 and you are using P3 cause I see tkinter and not Tkinter.

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do in `random2` but what you should be doing is calling self instead of creating a new instance. so delete this line: `s = First(root)` and change this line: `s.random()` to this: `self.random()` and you will get the same results without having to build a new instance of the class.

Comment: tbh I'm not good at coding I am trying to improve so I apologise for my bad coding manner. Thank you for the help @Mike-SMT .

Comment: I have done everything what you have mentioned and my code still functions properly, thank you @Mike-SMT

Comment: @AR_ we all have to start somewhere. I was not good at coding when I first started as well. But here I am 2 years later still learning and helping where I can :D. Just keep at it. You will get better. I added my answer as well to clear up some mistakes I noticed in your example. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Inheritance isn't for sharing data between objects. Each instance  is distinct and doesn't share information with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `super` on a class that is the highest in your hierarchy it will go `object`. `object` is the super class of all objects in Python. So `super(First, self).__init__(master)` will try to initialize the `object` not any of your classes. You can see this inheritance using the `Class.__mro__`. To figure out what I'm talking about.

And inheriting from object? That happens by default even if you don't specify anything. So I guess you wanted to inherit from `Frame` as `object` doesn't make any sense.

So change your code to this and it should be fixed.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
class First(Frame): # changed here
    def random(self):
        self._y = random.randint(11,20)
        self._x = random.randint(1,10)
    def random2(self):
        s = First(root)
        s.random()


class Second(First): # changed here 
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Second, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.menuFrame = Frame(self)
        self.create_menu_widgets()
        self.menuFrame.grid()
    def create_menu_widgets(self):
          btnMainMenu = Button(self.menuFrame,font=("consolas",18,"bold"),text="Main Menu")
          btnMainMenu.pack()
    def print(self):
        print(self._y,self._x)

root = Tk()
x = Second(root)
x.random()
x.random2()
x.print()
root.configure(background   = 'green') # you cannot see this as your button fills everything
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are still a few minor problems Mike - SMT is addressing in comments above.

Comment: Thank you Sir, this helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues in your example.

1:

you are assigning `Second()` to `x` but then calling `x.random()` and `x.random2()`. This will not work as your random methods only exist in the `First()` class.

2:

Don't name a function, method, variable or attribute the same thing as a built in method. This will cause problems.

Change your `def print(self)` to something like `def my_print(self)` or anything that is not exactly `print`. While we are talking about this print statement you only define `self._x` and `self._y` in your `First()` class but try to print them in your `Second()` class. This will never work. `self` is always a reference to the class object and never a reference to a class controller that was passed to the class.

Now I get what you are trying to do here and I will rebuild your code to show how to share information between classes.

You should not use a geometry manager fro inside the Frame class. Instead use it on the class variable name. This will allow you chose between any geometry manager for the class instead of sticking to just one kind.

As Vineeth pointed out you do not use supper for an object class.

The below code will run the `Second()` class and then when you want to reference the random methods on the `First()` class you can do so with the new methods I added to `Second()`. Let me know if you have any questions.

One last change is to import tkinter as `tk` this will help prevent accidentally overwriting an imported method from tkinter.

Here is a working example of your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class First(object):
    def random(self):
        return "From First.Random!", random.randint(11,20), random.randint(1,10)

    def random2(self):
        return "From First.Random2!", self.random()


class Second(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Second, self).__init__(master)
        self.menuFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.menuFrame.grid()
        tk.Button(self.menuFrame, font=("consolas", 18, "bold"), text="Main Menu").pack()

    def random(self):
        print(First().random())
    def random2(self):
        print(First().random2())


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='green')

x = Second(root)
x.pack()
x.random()
x.random2()

root.mainloop()
```